# Binding values from an a element

Tags: angular, two-way-binding

I am trying to bind the value from an "a" element:

**-template.component.html:**

```
  <form>
    <ul *ngFor="let city of cities">
      <a (click)="directToViewByCity()" [(ngModel)]="city.city" name="name">{{city.city}}  </a>
    </ul>
</form>
```

-**template.component.ts:**

```
directToViewByCity(selectedCity){
    this._router.navigate(['viewByCity'])

    var selectedCity=selectedCity;
    console.log(selectedCity)
  }
```

To be asigned to the variable selectedCity in the component.ts, but I am having this error:

`core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'name'
Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'name'`

I have tried several solutions, and I have donde a research on the internet, but I haven´t already found the proper solution.

Comment: why it is in form?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `ngModel`? What are you trying to set on the `a` tag?

Comment: you are not passing through a parameter to the function but you are trying to use it within the function.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need form and ngModel, you can just do the following:

```
<ul *ngFor="let city of cities">
    <a (click)="directToViewByCity(city)">{{city.city}}</a>
</ul>
```